# I am trying to make a value limited RSVP System

Tags: column, choice-field, formula

I have been tasked with creating a list in SharePoint to let users pick one of three training sessions. Each training session must be limited to 50 users.

I've been leaning towards a list with a firstname column, lastname column, and a choice column. the choice column will have 3 sessions (day 1, day 2, day 3) that users can sign up for.

Problem is, I've been struggling to figure out how to limit each selection on the choice column to 50 users per session.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Are you allowed to use custom JavaScript code?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, we are using sharepoint 2016, We do not currently use any custom javascript code but would be open to using it.